How to add X-CorrelationToken header to open telemetry java agent so that logs can be searched
Our font end sends X-CorrelationToken header to all our backend API calls, and we write this token to every log entry, so we can search log files (via ELK) when an error occurs in a call.
We need to get this header value as an attribute into new relic APM.
This is how we did it when we used the new relic java APM agent (via newrelic.yml):
transaction_events:
   custom_request_headers:
     - header_name: "X-CorrelationToken"

Now we need to figure out how to do the same thing with open telemetry, so we can link our log lines with service traces.
This is the otel java agent: https://opentelemetry.io/docs/zero-code/java/agent/getting-started/
From the docs and various posts we found the following relevant agent config params:
otel.instrumentation.http.client.capture-request-headers=X-CorrelationToken
otel.instrumentation.http.capture-headers.client.request=X-CorrelationToken
otel.instrumentation.common.experimental.capture-http-headers.client.request=X-CorrelationToken
otel.instrumentation.common.experimental.capture-http-headers.server.request=X-CorrelationToken
otel.instrumentation.http.capture-headers.server.request=X-CorrelationToken

But sadly, none of these work (i.e. there is no X-CorrelationToken attribute against spans or traces in New Relic for services which use the otel java agent).
Any suggestions? It must be a common use case.
Below is where we see the X-CorrelationToken attribute with the newrelic java agent, we want the same or similar using opentel agent.

